# how to monitor the duration of an http request with Observables Angular 4.x

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular2-observables

how to monitor the duration of an http request with Observables Angular 4.x before timeoutWith (30s)?

Basically, I want to trigger an event in Application Insights after 5s.

My code:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
        this.service.obterContextos(params.IdentificadoresExternos)
            .timeoutWith(environment.tempoLimiteCarregamento, Observable.defer(() =>
                Observable.throw(this.alertarTimeOut())))
            .subscribe(
                data => {

                });

        this.appInsightsService.trackEvent('Telemetria - Cartão de Crédito',
            telemetriaAI);
        parent.postMessage(response, '*');
    });
```

Comment: So your example code times out and throws the `alertarTimeOut` after 30 seconds, but you're asking how to trigger an event after 5 seconds regardless of the 30 second timeout?

Comment: Exact. When the request reaches 5s, I want to call a custom function, as it is already done at timeout

Comment: I understand less now ... so you want it to timeout after 30 seconds, then wait 5 seconds and call the function?

Comment: We want to monitor the classic timeout after waiting 30s. But we also want to trigger an event for the application insights an alert "look, the resquest has gone from 5s"

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want to make an API call that times out with an error after 30 seconds. If the API call takes longer than 5 seconds, you want it to continue and use the data from the API but also track this as an event. If the API call completes in less than 5 seconds, don't track the event and use the data from the API as normal. I would actually do this using two separate observables: one for the 5 second timeout and the other for the service request itself.

A much simpler version can be illustrated like so:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { defer } from 'rxjs/observable/defer';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';    
import { delay, timeoutWith, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

// The http request
const obs$ = of('Got the data');

const response$ = obs$.pipe(
  delay(simulateDelay), // simulate the time it takes to complete the http request

  // timeout error
  timeoutWith(30000, defer(() => _throw('took too long -- error'))),
);

// handle data or error when request completes or times out
response$.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
  err => console.log(err),
);

// track event that the request is taking long after 5 seconds,
// but only if request has not completed yet
obs$.pipe(
  delay(5000),
  takeUntil(response$),
).subscribe(() => console.log('taking kinda long!'));
```

Using your code I think you would write it like so:

```
const request$ = this.service.obterContextos(params.IdentificadoresExternos);
  .timeoutWith(environment.tempoLimiteCarregamento, Observable.defer(() =>
    Observable.throw(this.alertarTimeOut())))

request$.subscribe(data => { /* handle data */ });

timer(5000).pipe(takeUntil($request)).subscribe(() => {
    this.appInsightsService.trackEvent('Telemetria - Cartão de Crédito',
        telemetriaAI);
    parent.postMessage(response, '*');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pills, I'll test this solution as it seems to be more elegant.
I implemented something temporary, like this:

A timer before the service call:
    let timer = Observable.timer (1000, 1000);
A susscribe that increments ticks to the global variable:
    timer.subscribe (t => this.monitoraTempoCarregamento (t));
 monitoraTempoCarregamento(tick) {
    this.ticks = tick;
  }
And finally the request:
.finally(() => {
          if (this.ticks >= environment.alertaCarregamentoContextos) { // CALL EVENT HERRE }}